# how to pass an image from image picker to another view

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

Seems a bit old but i cannot work this out....have been busy with this now for a quite some time and i cannot find a working example to go about this so if somebody could help it would be appreciated, i am just trying to pass an image from a view controller to another view using image picker, i have 2 view controllers: viewcontroller and second view,  i am putting here the code for the view controller h file :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
 {
UIImagePickerController *picker;
IBOutlet UIImageView *selectedImage;
SecondView *imageView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *selectedImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) SecondView *secondView;
-(IBAction)sendImage:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)openGallery:(id)sender;
@end
```

here the m file of view controller :

```
 #import "ViewController.h"
 @interface ViewController ()
 @end
 @implementation ViewController
 @synthesize selectedImage;
 @synthesize secondView;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
 }

- (IBAction)secondView:(id)sender { if(self.secondView == nil)
{
    SecondView *secView = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    self.secondView = secView;
    secView.theImage = selectedImage.image;
}
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondView animated:YES];
}

 -(IBAction)sendImage:(id)sender
{
if(self.secondView == nil)
    {
        SecondView *secView = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        self.secondView = secView;
        secView.theImage = selectedImage.image;
    }
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondView animated:YES];
}
objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
-(IBAction)openGallery:(id)sender
{
  picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
  picker.delegate = self;
  picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
  [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *) Picker
{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[Picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *) Picker
    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
selectedImage.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondView animated:YES];
[Picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
@end
```

here is the h file of secondview :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondView : UIViewController
{
UIImageView *imgView;
UIImage *theImage;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *theImage;

-(void)setImage:(UIImage *)image;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

@end
```

here is the m file of secondview :

```
#import "SecondView.h"

@interface SecondView ()

@end

@implementation SecondView : UIViewController

@synthesize imgView;
@synthesize theImage;

-(void)setImage:(UIImage *)image
{
[imgView setImage:image];

}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[_imageView setImage:theImage];
}
- (void)loadView {
 self.title = @"Photo";
_imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame];
self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
self.imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.view = self.imageView;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
 [super viewWillAppear:animated];
 [_imageView setImage:theImage];
 }
 @end
```

i just keep on getting a blank screen on second view....any help greatly appreciated....thanks in advance....

Comment: sendImage button segue is attached with 2nd viewcontroller ?

Comment: thank you....no it's not attached with a segue....but am trying your suggested code....will keep posted....thankx again

Comment: ok...thank you....my secondView was in a navigation controller....took out the navigation controller and put your code in m file of view controller and named segue "segue" and bob's my uncle...dada.....it works....thank you shush nath...

Comment: don't forget to accept answer, green correct mark option at answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if button is attached with segue on second viewcontroller use this code.

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
SecondView *secView = segue.destinationViewController;
self.secondView = secView;
secView.theImage = selectedImage.image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a new `UIImageView` on other `view controller` and pass this image using `prepareForSegue` method.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
 if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"editphoto"])
 {
   YourNextViewController*editImageView=segue.destinationViewController;
   UIImage*clickedImage=capturedPicImageView.image;
  editImageView.passedImage=clickedImage;
 }
}
```

And in `YourNextViewController` create `UIImage*clickedImage` and give **property** to it. and        **dont forget to allocate in `viewDidLoad`**. Hope this helps.

Comment: no not working for me....i have to change too many things in my classes....the reason i gave all the code was to get a very precise answer....and previous worked for me....but t thanks all the same for coming back to me.